# How to use JSON Conditional Formatting to disable/"Grey out" a column based on 2 other columns in SharePoint Online?

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Some context: I am using a SharePoint site for one of my clients. They use it to manage their jobs with their clients. I have 3 relevant fields here: Ready to Bill, Checked In, and Close Job. Ready to Bill is a choice field, with choices: Yes, No, Invoiced. Checked In is a date and time field. Close Job is a check box.

Client would like to delete the job after it is marked under the "Close Job" field. To prevent accidental deletion, he specified that he wants "Close Job" to be read-only until "Ready to Bill" is marked "Invoiced" AND "Checked In" is not empty. Then I will just make a Power Automate flow to check when Close Job is checked and delete the entire list item.

My thought is to use JSON conditional formatting on the "Close Job" column to essentially disable the column unless those 2 parameters are met.

How would you guys approach this? Does anyone know how I would write the JSON for this?

I have not tried anything yet, because I do not know where to begin. It doesn't seem correct to do this in Power Apps.

Comment: I don't think you can make the form fields disabled using JSON formatting. However, you can show/hide those fields based on SharePoint conditional formulas.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP 
Is the process simple? Where do I apply the conditional formulas if not in the advanced format settings, aka JSON?

Comment: You can hide the "Close Job" check box from list forms until the necessary conditions met using conditional formula. Check the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot make the SharePoint Yes/No column disabled from SharePoint list forms using the JSON formatting.

However, you can try below workaround:

1. Set default value of Close Job (Yes/No) column to "No".
2. Then you can hide the "Close Job" check box from list forms until the necessary conditions met using conditional formula.
3. Once those conditions met, Close Job check box will be visible on the list form and users can check it.

Here is the example conditional formula which you can use:

```
=if([$ReadyToBill]=='Invoiced' && Number([$CheckedIn])!=0, 'true', 'false')
```

Replace `ReadyToBill` and `CheckedIn` in above formula with the actual **internal names** of your SharePoint list columns. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

I have used `Number([$CheckedIn])!=0` to check if date and time column is blank or not. You can find other ways to check the same at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

Follow this Microsoft documentation for steps to apply the conditional formula to Close Job column: [Specify conditional formula to show or hide SharePoint list form columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#specify-conditional-formula-to-show-or-hide-columns)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the way to go, however it will not work for me.

In the "Show or hide SharePoint list form" article, it is stated that Choice columns will not work with the conditional formatting.

_Unsupported column types in conditional formulas
While the formula supports many of the available column types, we do not currently support the following column types:_

Person or Group with multiple selections, 
**Choice with multiple selections**, 
Time calculations in Date and Time column, 
Currency columns, 
Location columns, 
Calculated columns
Managed Metadata columns

Comment: Is your "ReadyToBill" column of type single selection choice column or multiple selection choice column? It should work if it is a single selection choice column. Check the column settings once.